# popViewControllerAnimated: results in unresponsive view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, containers

I have used navigation controllers many times but have never come across this.

I have my root view controller which is a custom built container controller having a tabbar at the bottom sitting inside a navigation controller.  I had to build a custom container for various reasons...anyways...I click on an image in one of the cells and I push a detail view. (I am not using didselectrowatindexpath for various reasons, the app knows that an image is clicked on a cell because of a delegate that registers those touches).

Then there is a close button on the detail view and I click it and execute popViewControllerAnimated:  This all works fine and once the view is popped the starting (one who pushed the detail view) viewcontroller is displayed.  Only issue is that now I am unable to handle any touches on the screen.  It is as if the app is frozen and just sits there after popping the view.  Am I missing anything?  I assume all you have to do for navigation controllers is just push and pop.  No delegates or anything like that.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: did you find a solution to this?